# Constructor Function is not working properly

Tags: c++

I wrote a constructor function for a class RandomGame which inherits from a different class, SGGame. However, the constructor is not functioning properly.

It is supposed to create a stochastic game with random payoffs and transition probabilities given interger inputs of number of players, actions, and states. Right now, it is always creating a game with two players, one state, and one action, regardless of inputs.

Here is the constructor function:

````
class RandomGame : public SGGame
{
private:
  int numactions;
public:
  RandomGame(int numPlayers,
             int numStates,
             int numactions)
  {

          unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
          std::default_random_engine generator (seed);

          std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(1e-6,1-(1e-6));
          double delta = distribution(generator);

          vector<bool> unconstrained(numPlayers,false);

          vector< vector< int > > numActions(numStates,vector<int>(numPlayers,numactions));
          vector<int> numActions_total(numStates,pow(numactions, numPlayers));

  // Payoffs

          vector< vector< vector<double> > >
                  payoffs(numStates,vector< vector<double> >(pow(numactions, numPla
yers),vector<double>(numPlayers,0.0)));
          unsigned int i,j,k,l;
          for(i=0;i<numStates;i++)
          {
            for(j=0;j<numActions_total[i];j++)
            {
               for(k=0;k<numPlayers;k++)
               {
                 std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0,10);

                 payoffs[i][j][k] = distribution(generator);
               }
            }
          }
  // Transition probabilities
          vector < vector< vector<double> > >
                  probabilities(numStates,vector< vector<double> >(pow(numactions,
numPlayers), vector<double>(numStates,1.0))); // 1.0 as initial value, but then ran
domize
          // randomize transition probabilities
          double prob_sum;
          for(i=0;i<numStates;i++)
          {
            for(j=0;j<numActions_total[i];j++)
            {
              prob_sum = 0.0;
              for(k=0;k<numStates;k++)
              {
                std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0,1.0);
                probabilities[i][j][k] = distribution(generator);
                // normalize probabilities
                prob_sum += probabilities[i][j][k];
              }
              for(k=0;k<numStates;k++)
              {
                probabilities[i][j][k] = probabilities[i][j][k]/prob_sum;
              }
            }
          }
          SGGame game(delta,
                      numStates,
                      numActions,
                      payoffs,
                      probabilities,
                      unconstrained);
  }

}; ```

// decleration of the class SGGame: the constructor I call at the bottom of that code uses an SGGame constructor which creates an SGGame with the given inputs. 

``` ```
class SGGame
{
private:
  double delta; /*!< The discount factor. */
  int numPlayers; /*!< The number of players. */
  int numStates; /*!< The number of states, must be at least 1. */
  vector< vector<int> > numActions; /*!< Gives the number of each
                                       player's actions in each
                                       state. In particular, player i
                                       has numActions[s][i] actions in
                                       state s. Should note that a
                                       pair (a1,a2) is mapped into an
                                       action profile using the
                                       formula
                                       a=a1+a2*numActions[s][a1], and
                                       generalized to n>2. */
  vector<int> numActions_total; /*!< Total number of action profiles
                                   for each state. */

  vector< vector<SGPoint> > payoffs; /*!< Gives the payoffs of the
                                        players as a function of the
                                        action profile. In particular,
                                        payoffs[s][a][i] are player
                                        i's payoffs in state s when
                                        action profile a is played. */

  vector< vector< vector<double> > > probabilities; /*!< State
                                                       transition
                                                       probabilities:
                                                       probabilities[s][a][s']
                                                       is the
                                                       probability of
                                                       transitioning
                                                       to state s'
                                                       when action
                                                       profile a is
                                                       played in state
                                                       s. */
 vector< vector<bool> > eqActions; /*!< Indicates which action profiles
                                   are allowed to be played on path in
                                   each state. By default, initialized
                                   to true for all action
                                   profiles. Allows one to, for
                                   example, look at strongly symmetric
                                   equilibria (by first excluding
                                   asymmetric action profiles from the
                                   lists). Players can always deviate
                                   to action profiles which are not
                                   allowed on path. */

  vector<bool> unconstrained; /*!< If unconstrained[i]=true, the
                                 algorithm will not impose incentive
                                 compatibility as a constraint for
                                 player i. */ ```

// call to the constructor which is not working properly: 
``` ```
RandomGame game(2,3,4); ```
````

Comment: Are you sure this is a minimal example? Have you checked whether your randomisation works without use of any other classes?

Comment: `SGGame game(delta,
                      numStates,
                      numActions,
                      payoffs,
                      probabilities,
                      unconstrained);` looks suspicious in the constructor. It looks like you create a local variable `game` which ends its scope at closing `}`

Comment: `SGGame game(delta, numStates, numActions, payoffs, probabilities, unconstrained);` creates a temporary object of type `SGGame` and immediately destroys it. That's almost always a mistake. But with all the (probably irrelevant) code in that constructor, it's not possible to say for sure without putting in a great deal of time that wouldn't be necessary if you removed code that doesn't contribute to the problem.

Comment: Your code is neither minimal, nor sufficient to understand your issue, and what you're trying to express with that code... You said "it is always creating a game with two players, one state, and one action, regardless of inputs", but how do you know that? Where is the code that leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We ask that people pot [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/hlp/mcve) of malfunctioning code, and this is not just for our benefit. When you write code, it behooves you to build up from the simple to the complex, testing often, and developing new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. In a case like this, when you have written a lot of tightly coupled code since your last test, it's best to retreat: pare away code, testing at every step, until the error disappears. This will make the bug  much easier to see.

Comment: I expect  the  the problem is you are not initializing the base `SGGame` of `RandomGame`. Instead you create a new `SGGame` that has no connection to the one that is the base of `RandomGame`. That new one `game` goes out of scope and all of your randomization work is thrown away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your constructor, you create the `SGGame` object, but don't actually do anything with it. It's just discarded.

Because `SGGame` is a base class of `RandomGame`, the logic inside your constructor should be moved into it's own function, which can then be passed to the constructor for `SGGame`.

We'll call this function `generateRandomGame`:

```
class RandomGame : public SGGame {
private:
  int numactions;

public:
  RandomGame(int numPlayers, int numStates, int numactions)
    : SGGame(generateRandomGame(numPlayers, numStates, numactions))
    , numactions(numactions) {}
  // Other stuff...
};
```

Based on the code in your original constructor, `generateRandomGame` should look something like this:

```
SGGame generateRandomGame(int numPlayers, int numStates, int numactions) {

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(1e-6, 1 - (1e-6));
    double delta = distribution(generator);

    vector<bool> unconstrained(numPlayers, false);

    vector<vector<int>> numActions(numStates,
                                   vector<int>(numPlayers, numactions));
    vector<int> numActions_total(numStates, pow(numactions, numPlayers));

    // Payoffs

    vector<vector<vector<double>>> payoffs(
        numStates, vector<vector<double>>(pow(numactions, numPlayers),
                                          vector<double>(numPlayers, 0.0)));
    unsigned int i, j, k, l;
    for (i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numActions_total[i]; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < numPlayers; k++) {
                std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, 10);

                payoffs[i][j][k] = distribution(generator);
            }
        }
    }
    // Transition probabilities
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> probabilities(
        numStates,
        vector<vector<double>>(
            pow(numactions, numPlayers),
            vector<double>(numStates,
                           1.0))); // 1.0 as initial value, but then randomize
    // randomize transition probabilities
    double prob_sum;
    for (i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numActions_total[i]; j++) {
            prob_sum = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < numStates; k++) {
                std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, 1.0);
                probabilities[i][j][k] = distribution(generator);
                // normalize probabilities
                prob_sum += probabilities[i][j][k];
            }
            for (k = 0; k < numStates; k++) {
                probabilities[i][j][k] = probabilities[i][j][k] / prob_sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return SGGame(delta, numStates, numActions, payoffs, probabilities,
                  unconstrained);
}
```